# PouchDB data gets deleted after app quits

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, pouchdb

The problem that a came across is that when i close my app using `navigator.app.exitApp();` the data in my PouchDB gets deleted... This is very strange situation, i think there is some kind of open transaction or something like that. I saw that there is method(without documentation) `db.close()` and i call it before quit the app, but still no success.

I open the database like that:

```
db = new PouchDB('MyDB', {adapter : 'websql', size: 100});
```

I'm using Cordova with Android platform.
PouchDB adapter:**websql**
PouchDB version:**5.1.0.min.js** i tried and with **5.2.1.min.js** and still the same...

Comment: There are no logs showing some error or anything else pointing what the problem is...

Comment: After a deep debugging i extract the db from device's file-explorer and saw that is not empty!!!, but when access it from javascript it tells me that the db is empty...
It looks that is locked or something like that...

Answer (score 1):

`db.close()` is non-standard and will probably be removed. In the case of WebSQL, it does nothing.

This error is very mysterious to me - are you writing a hybrid app or a webapp? Which version of Android? Did you try IndexedDB instead of WebSQL? What happens if you change the `size` parameter (I don't usually use it for Android, only iOS)?